# No wifi after changing provider / sim card

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean, connection-issues, 3g, proxy

Last Monday I changed provider and got a new simcard. I can use the phone and send SMS/text messages. Internet didn't work anymore. Wifi didn't work anymore. Both have not worked since. I do see the 3G or GPRS icon in the statusbar. I see the Wifi icon, and it's connected to the right network. I've tried this on several locations.

The provider says they have a problem since Tuesday (not Monday), so 3G does not work. What baffles me is that wifi doesn't work anymore.

Last weekend I've tried to get a paid proxy service working on my laptop, which didn't work for some reason. I installed OpenVPN on my phone. I didn't configure the proxy service on the phone however. I removed OpenVPN yesterday to be sure. I have used internet on the phone since installing OpenVPN, so I guess that can't be the problem.

On Twitter I read about someone using the same network who could still use Whatsapp, so I tried that, and then saw a popup "unable to resolve host ota.avatarrom.com" (or something like that - it disappeared too soon). I've installed Avatarrom several months ago, and although I have problems with it (Settings crashes on and on), it works reasonably. Whatsapp couldn't connect by the way. The phone: Samsung Galaxy S2.

The provider can't tell when their problems are over. I'm curious if that will solve anything, we'll see.

Can you explain this? What can I do to get Wifi working again?

Comment: As always in cases like that, a `logcat` might prove helpful. If you can, connect your device via USB to your computer and run `adb logcat -f logfile.log` while trying to connect to your WiFi and access the net. Then stop logging, and investigate `logfile.log` for clues (of couse, you can name the file anything you want and your OS permits ;)

Comment: I just found out that disabling the AFwall+ firewall solved my problems. Suddenly everything works. This has worked with the previous provider, and I don't understand how changing the simcard can result in this.

Comment: If someone can explain this, I'll approve that answer!

Comment: Without more information (logs), we only can guess. Maybe it's a coincidence, and you've changed something in AFWall+ at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that disabling the AFwall+ firewall solved my problems. Now everything works. This has worked with the previous provider, and I don't understand how changing the simcard can result in this.